# Get node names that have a specific role

Tags: chef, knife

How can I get list of nodes, that have a specific role?

It could be got with something like that:

```
for node in `knife node list`; do
  [[ -n "`knife node show $node | grep $ROLE_NAME`" ]] &&  echo $node
done
```

Is there a way to doing it via knife without bash overhead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a solution:

```
knife search node "roles:$ROLE_NAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

The header from "knife search" is output to stderr, so you can use

```
knife search "role:$ROLE_NAME" -i 2>/dev/null
```

to just return a list of nodes.  Useful if you want to wrap that into a for statement:

```
for n in $(knife search "role:$ROLE_NAME" -i 2>/dev/null); do
  // do something here
done
```